# copy item/document in same list,using OOTB workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I want to create new column and in that column I want any link/button  and after clicking on it I want to make copy of same document/item inside same library/list.

Is it possible with OOTB workflow?

Answer (score 0):

The basic SharePoint designer workflow has only three types of trigger as listed below,

1. Trigger the workflow when a item is created
2. Trigger the workflow when a item is edited
3. Manual trigger of workflow

Hope you were aware how all these triggers work.

So, you cannot start a workflow on a click of a link. Either you should use some javascript to trigger a workflow or complete the entire copying task through JavaScript.

And the most simple way is create a designer workflow to copy item and use manual trigger option to perform the task.